# How to filter using ddply

Tags: r, subset, plyr

I have data:

```
df<- data.frame(Plot = rep(rep(1:3,each = 2),3), Year = rep(1:3,each = 6), 
                D = rep(c(1,1,5,NA,2,2,2,1,5),2), HT = rep(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,3,2,NA,4,5),2))


   Plot Year  D HT
1     1    1  1 NA
2     1    1  1 NA
3     2    1  5 NA
4     2    1 NA NA
5     3    1  2  3
6     3    1  2  2
7     1    2  2 NA
8     1    2  1  4
9     2    2  5  5
10    2    2  1 NA
11    3    2  1 NA
12    3    2  5 NA
13    1    3 NA NA
14    1    3  2  3
15    2    3  2  2
16    2    3  2 NA
17    3    3  1  4
18    3    3  5  5
```

I understand that using `ddply()` in the `plyr` package allows me to count how many of each plot-year combo exists

```
ddply(df, .(df[,"Plot"], df[,"Year"]), nrow)
```

However, I also want to determine how many rows exist *given* that HT is not NA (or alternatively if D > 1). I want to append this info as a new column on the output from ddply above.

- I thought about just subsetting the DF for the data argument, but doing so would eliminate possible plot-year combinations which would make adjoining columns from the un-subsetted and subsetted outputs more difficult (i.e., using something like `merge()`).

**Is there a way to subset data in ddply using a subset of values in one or more of the data.frame's columns?**

Update: Desired Output

```
   Plot Year Count HaveHt
1     1    1     2     0
2     1    2     2     1
3     1    3     2     1
4     2    1     2     0
5     2    2     2     1
6     2    3     2     1
7     3    1     2     2
8     3    2     2     0
9     3    3     2     2
```

- I understand that this output would be compiled by appending (cbinding) columns from 2 separate variants of the code...

Comment: You can do `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Plot, Year) %>% mutate(n = sum(!is.na(HT)))` or using `plyr` `plyr::ddply(df, c("Plot", "Year"), mutate, n = sum(!is.na(HT)))`

Comment: @Akrun, thanks. but I want to count each instance for the given plot-year combo.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show the expected output column.  I am not sure what you wanted

Comment: I wanted output similar to `ddply(df, .(df[,"Plot"], df[,"Year"]), nrow)`. I see now that you included the n column to get me the info I need. I was just distracted by the other columns (D and HT) still showing up in the output

Comment: The `n` column created is `plyr::ddply(df, c("Plot", "Year"), mutate, n = sum(!is.na(HT)))$n#
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2`  I hope it is what you wanted

Comment: Yes thanks. I get it now. Please draft as an answer and I will upvote :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `plyr`, then with summarise the column by specifying the `summarise` and get the `sum` of logical vector i.e.. non NA elements of HT (`!is.na(HT)`) after grouping by the columns and also the count with `length`

```
plyr::ddply(df, c("Plot", "Year"), summarise, n = length(HT), HaveHt = sum(!is.na(HT)))
```

---

The same can be done with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Plot, Year) %>% 
    summarise(Count = n(), HaveHt = sum(!is.na(HT)))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups: Plot [?]
#   Plot  Year Count HaveHt
#  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1     1     2      0
#2     1     2     2      1
#3     1     3     2      1
#4     2     1     2      0
#5     2     2     2      1
#6     2     3     2      1
#7     3     1     2      2
#8     3     2     2      0
#9     3     3     2      2
```

Comment: Actually I just realized that this spits out a data.frame with dimensions equal to the original data input. I was hoping to have the output "shrunk" down to just include each plot and year combination in increasing order (i.e., the rows would have first 2 columns as plot 1 year 1, p1y2, p1y3, p2y1, p2y2, ...). In other words, rows with duplicate plot-year combos would be removed

Comment: @theforestecologist  Could you please include the expected output in your post.  It is not clear to me

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I realized my example was not complete enough to reflect my actual data. I've updated my post with a new example data set and example of desired ouput. Thanks for your help